# modulo of sums of consective powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am thinking of whether there is any pattern about sums of consective powers mod $m$.

Assume $m$,$n$,$k$ are integers.
Denote $$f_k(n)=1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k,$$

The question is:
how does $f_k(n)$ behave modulo $m$, especially in that case that $k=n$ and $(m,n)=1?$

Comment: incidentally I am also wondering about this problem for last one week.

Comment: There might be some useful information for you, if you search for Agoh/Giuga-conjecture. This covers only a special case (k=n-1 or k=n+1, don't have it at hand) but possibly gives you some hints where you can start from/proceede from or which simply pushes you forward...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks.

Comment: For $k$ fixed, I find it unlikely that $f_k(n)$ will behave nicely modulo primes dividing $(k+1)!$.  This is due to the fact that $f_k(n) \in \mathbb{Q}[n]$ has denominator with these primes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a paper of mine showing the precise power of $2$ dividing such sums: http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2275

The general case is far more difficult, of course… but for regular primes, there are some easy ways to determine the exact power. From that, your "modulo" question is likely easy to determine.